# Blender Geometry Nodes - Randomly Translate Faces Along Normal

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

How could the individual faces of a mesh be randomly translated in relation to its own normal's XYZ? Currently the faces are translated uniformly on the normal's Z axis only:

[image]

Comment: You could use the node `Random Value`, and scale the vector with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just to be able to mark this question as solved, here is a short answer from the comments:

In order to be able to move the faces along their normals with random values, you would need to scale the normals with a randomly generated value and capture them in the domain *Face* with the node `Capture Attribute`.

These resulting direction vectors will then serve you as *offset* in the node `Set Position`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>